# How update image using Angular 6

Tags: angular, typescript

I using Angular 6 and Firebase. I want to update an image on the server.

This is my html:

```
<div class="form-check">
    <input type="file" (change)="onFileSelected($event)">
  </div>
```

This is my variable     `selectedFile = null;`

My method in component:

```
 onFileSelected(event) {

this.selectedFile = event.target.file[0];
```

}

And I have this error:

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Do anyone know what I have this error?

Comment: Apperently the property `file` is undefined. try to `console.log` `event` and see what properties it has

Comment: Should be `.files` not `.file`

Comment: Oh, my mistake. Thanks a lot. I make mistake with .file but correctly is .files

Answer (score 0):

```
onFileSelected(e) {
    this.selectedFile = e && e.target.files.length > 0 ? e.target.files[0] : '';
}
```

---

```
const formData: FormData = new FormData();
formData.append('image', this.selectedFile);
let headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers = headers.delete('Content-Type');
const url = `upload/url`
this.httpClient.post(url, formData, { headers: headers });
```